# Why does Titchmarsh say that we can move the derivative under $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\Xi(t)}{t^2 + \frac{1}{4}} \cosh(\alpha t) \, dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

If we define the Riemann-Xi function as $$ \Xi(t) = \xi(\frac{1}{2} + it)$$ where $$\xi(s) = \frac{1}{2}s(s-1)\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s),$$

then according to Titchmarsh in his adaptation of Hardy's proof that the zeta function has infinitely many zeros on the critical line, if we consider the integral

$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\Xi(t)}{t^2 + \frac{1}{4}} \cosh(\alpha t) dt, $$ then "since $\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it) = O(t^A)$, $\Xi(t) = O(t^Ae^{-\frac{1}{4}\pi t})$, and the above integral may be differentiated with respect to $\alpha$ any number of times provided that $\alpha < \frac{1}{4}\pi$."

I don't really understand either of the claims; that is, why is $\Xi(T) = O(t^Ae^{-\frac{1}{4}\pi t})$ and why does this imply that we can move the derivative under the integral sign any number of times as long as $\alpha < \frac{1}{4}$.  Can someone explain these things?

Here is my work so far:

After plugging the definition of $\xi(s)$ into the definition of $\Xi(t)$ we get that

$$ \Xi(t) = \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{4} - t^2)\pi^{-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{it}{2})\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it).$$

I can prove that for $|t| \geq 1$ and $Re(s) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, $|\zeta(s)| \leq |t|^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon}$ and I can also show that $|\Gamma(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{it}{2})| \leq \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{|t|}. $

Additionally, $|\pi^{-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2}}| = \pi^{-\frac{1}{4}} = e^{-\frac{1}{4} \log(\pi)}$.  I'm stuck after this.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound on the $\Xi$ function is given by [Stirling's formula for the Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function). The main contributing term is $$\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}}=\exp\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\log\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\right)$$ and by the definition of [the complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) this is  $$=\exp\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\log|\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}|+i\arg\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\right).$$ Now, $\arg\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right),$ and so by combining in the other terms we have that $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)=O\left(t^{A}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\pi t}\right)$$ for some constant $A$.

As for the differentiation under the integration sign, this works since our function is infinitely differentiable and decays very quickly. Theorem 2.27 (b) of Folland's Real Analysis states that

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $f:X\times [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and that $f(\cdot,t):X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is integratable for each $t\in[a,b]$. Let $F(t)=\int_X f(x,t)d\mu(x)$. Suppose that $\partial f/\partial t$ exists and that there is a real $g\in L^1(\mu)$ such that $|(\partial f/\partial t)(x,t)|\leq g(x)$ for all $x,t$. Then $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=\int (\partial f/\partial t)(x,t)d\mu(x)$.

And from this we see that the decay condition is enough to differentiate as many times as we would like. Alternatively, we may use the theorem appearing [on the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign):

> **Theorem** Let $f(x,t)$ be a function such that both $f(x,t)$ and its partial derivative $f_x(x,t)$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region containing $a(x)\leq t\leq b(x)$, $x_0\leq x\leq x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0\leq x\leq x_1$.  Then for '$x_0\leq x\leq x_1$:
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right) = f(x,b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(x,a(x))\cdot a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f_x(x,t)\; \mathrm{d}t.$$

In our case, all of the functions are infinitely differentiable and the decay condition removes the terms at $0$ and $\infty$ so that we may simply take the derivative under the integral sign.

Comment: Did you get that theorem from Folland's Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications 2nd edition or 1st edition?

Comment: Should that say $g \in L^1(u)$ instead of ``$f \in L^1(u)$"?

Comment: @nick corrected. Also I believe it is the second edition.